# Java FX - filling table rows in different colours

Tags: java, javafx

I updated my code to show how the whole class look like
Still I got some errors can you validate what I need to improve to have it working

Mainly the problem is with fillTableView() method

```
private TableCell fillTableView() {

    clientColumn.setCellFactory(column -> {
        return new TableCell<CarFx, String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                setText(empty ? "" : getItem().toString());
                setGraphic(null);

                TableRow<CarFx> currentRow = getTableRow();

                if (!isEmpty()) {

                    if (item.equals("EMPTY EMPTY"))
                        currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color:green");
                    else
                        currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color:blue");
                }
            }
        };
    });

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem (pointing to a gist is not good - answers to questions here are meant as reference solution, your link may or may not be available in future). Also, please search the fx tag - there have been several QAs recently for styling rows (vs. cells)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the items of Table View by overriding `updateItem()` method.

The code is :

```
  yourColumnBased.setCellFactory(column -> {
        return new TableCell<CarFx, String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                setText(empty ? "" : getItem().toString());
                setGraphic(null);

                TableRow<CarFx> currentRow = getTableRow();

                if (!isEmpty()) {

                    if(item.equals("assigned")) 
                        currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color:blue");
                    else
                        currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color:green");
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply, I updated my code above to give you insight how to whole class looks like, because it appear that I already have update item method in my code, could you tell me where exactly should I add your lines to avid duplication? I tried to add it in initialize() method but carsTableView cannot call for the method setCellFactory - The method setCellFactory((<no type> column) -> {}) is undefined for the type TableView<CarFx>

Comment: I also tried this way: this.carsTableView.(seach for methods) but setCellFactory does not appear in drop down menu

Comment: my another try was:  this.carsTableView.setRowFactory(column -> { so I changed Cell to Row... but then I have error in next line -  return new TableRow<CarFx, String>() { - Incorrect number of arguments for type TableRow<T>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <CarFx, String>

Comment: hmm.. maybe we should use clientColumn, then call for setCellFactory method somehow..

Comment: @TomekMłynarski,of course `setCellFactory` is defined method for `TableView` column,I edited my answer by replacing the object by your rent column.You can add my lines in separate method `fillTableView()` and call it from `initialize()` method.

Comment: this is what I try to do, I have a question could you have a look at my github repo because I updated the code but unfortunately I am doing still something not right

Comment: I updated code I wrote above, can you have a look why I still have some issues?

Comment: Please ,don't change your question each time to create new issue ,I provide an answer based on your first issue "How to make colors for my rows ?"